# Calling function without using ng-click inside ng-repeat- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="dateDetails in visitsDates | orderBy : dateDetails.date | filter : contactid | limitTo : 1">
    <tr>
        <td>Joint Work</td>
        <td>{{dateDetails.joint_work}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gap</td>
        <td><a href="" ng-click="gap(dateDetails.date)">Click Me</a></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

in above code, I have put ng-click, after which the function is called. But the function has to be called by default so as to populate one of the columns, which is not happening. the function 'gap' sets $scope.gap to the difference between today's date and the date passed to it. How should I fix the problem?

Comment: I suggest to pre-manipulate `visitsDates`, use Array#map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to do it with markup you can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Also, from the same link, can't you set up initial value using your controller?

Comment: Thanks @Darshan, it worked using ng-init.. thank you so much :)

Answer (score -2):

I achieved this function call inside ng-repeat by using ng-init

```
<td class="lectureClass" ng-repeat="s in sessions" ng-init='presenters=getPresenters(s.id)'>
      {{s.name}}
      <div class="presenterClass" ng-repeat="p in presenters">
          {{p.name}}
      </div>
</td>
```

The code on the controller side should look like below

```
$scope.getPresenters = function(id) {
    return SessionPresenters.get({id: id});
};
```

While the API factory is as follows:

```
angular.module('tryme3App').factory('SessionPresenters', function ($resource, DateUtils) {

        return $resource('api/session.Presenters/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET', isArray: true
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    });
```